# Find Text from content then hide using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, text

I am trying hide `specific` text element from content by jquery. Example below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="name">
Trying hide specific Text elements from content.
</div>
```

**I want this** by jquery:

```
<div id="name">
Trying hide <p style="display: none;">specific<p> Text elements from content.
</div>
```

There any simple solution by jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) method.

Also, use regex so you could hide **all** of them.

Like this:

```js
var hideElm = 'specific',
    regex = new RegExp(hideElm, 'g');

$('#name').html(function(i, html){
  return html.replace(regex, '<span style="display:none">' + hideElm + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name">
Trying hide specific Text elements from content. Another specific
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to remove that word from text in div then you could try this:

```
$('div:contains("Specific:")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("Specific:").join(""));
});
```

This will remove "Specific" word from all divs. you can put element ID to remove from particular div.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` method

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#name').html(function(index, text) {
      return text.replace('specific', '<p style="display:none;">specific</p>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name">
Trying hide specific Text elements from content.
</div>
<br />
<button>Hide</button>
```

Comment: `replace` it's not a jQuery method, but vanila javascript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```js
$('#name').click(function(){
$('#name p').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name">
Trying hide <p >specific</p> Text elements from content.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<p>` because it adds a new line.

Change your html:

```
<div id="name">
    Trying hide <span class="specific">specific</span> Text elements from content.
</div>
```

And add in the code:

```
$('.specific').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide p element inside main div by the following.

> $(#name > p).hide();

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it it's own paragraph, you can use a span. Assigning a class or id to that span would probably be best, but with what you have:

```
<div id="name">
Trying hide <p style="display: none;">specific<p> Text elements from content.
</div>

$(#name p).hide();
```

will work (find all paragraphs in the element with the name "name" and hide them)

Answer (score 0):

This is jquery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#name').find('.specific').hide();

    });
    </script>
```

This is HTML

```
 <div id="name">
            Trying hide <span class="specific">specific</span> Text elements from content.
    </div>
```